# Keep Text right of an image

Tags: css

If you look carefully at the page http://www.ribevi.com/red_wines.html

You can notice that the 5th wine AMARONE has some text that goes around and under the bottle image.

Is there a way to block that from happen and have ALL the Text on the Right side ...without having to create a tables inside that  ??

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `float` (left or right) an image inside a block element (like a `p`aragraph):

```
<p>
<img src="your-image">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
</p>

p img {
    float:left;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/bwYG4/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your data in a `div container` and `float` your `div` to the `right` and give some width to it :

Wrap your data using these styles on a container `div` and you can obviously make a class of it later :

```
<div style="width: 320px; text-align: justify; float: right;">
```

See this wine : `Montecariano Valpolicella Classico Superiore Ripasso`

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VJtqc/)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I did what they suggested but obviously you will need to change the values.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXj2N/

Comment: So this solution will force me to ALL have the same min height ..is that right ?

Comment: If you know your text isn't going to be longer than a certain length, it will work perfectly. But as you can see on the jsfiddle the text still lows back to the left when exceeding the length. I think for what you want, it would be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

quickest solution would be to set a margin-bottom on the image to prevent the text from going under it.

Update:

```
.tdCell img, .image {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: So I would need to set each individual image ..a different height, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create tables, and the gods of markup and stylesheets will look kindly upon you if you say, simply use `display: table-cell` CSS statement. It will do what you want, at least it's one of the perfectly modern and valid ways to do so. Remember that there is a difference between having `TABLE`s in your markup, which dictate purpose and intent (you are dealing with tables of values, for math, or other science, for example), and having `table-cell` style your markup to have your content **look** like tables do. In other words, in HTML+CSS world, if something may resemble a table on your device, it doesn't make it a table. Question people who would have you believe that tables are bad - they are not bad, per se. What is bad is putting `TABLE` tags in your documents where they don't belong. And let's face it, on average about 5% of all websites we have need tables. Styling your pages to make use of table-style rendering however, is perfectly fine.

```
<div style="height: 100%;"><!-- the children of this element will automatically occupy its entire height, courtesy of 'table-cell' rule. -->
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        <img src="example.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">
        Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        <!-- Wall of text follows... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The text "Quick brown ..." will *never* surround the image the way floating elements have text do. It will simply continue downward, keeping the area under the image clear at all times. Like stuff in tables does.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:600px; float:left; height:auto;">
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background-color:red; display: table-cell">left container</div>
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background-color:Green; display: table-cell">Mind container</div>
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background-color:Black; display: table-cell">right container</div>

</div>
```